# C macro to run a loop over a range

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have an **array** of 10 elements. An **arbitrary function** is to be called on that element.

Each arbitrary function can either

1. Operate on a single element, or
2. The same function will operate on all elements.

I have a variety of functions that follow this pattern.

I'm trying to do this:

```
#define ITERATE_ALL10(IDX) (##IDX = 0; ##IDX < 10; ##IDX++)

int arbitrary_fx(int *some_arr, int id) {
    int i;

    if (id == ID_ALL) {
        for (ITERATE_ALL10(i)) {
            arbitrary_fx_helper(some_arr[id]);
        }
    }
    else {
        arbitrary_fx_helper(some_arr[id]);
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to fix the errors:

```
expected ';' before ')' token
```

and

```
expected expression before ')' token
```

What have I done wrong? Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Why do you use the token pasting operator? It is not required here.

Comment: Either remove the parentheses from the macro definition or remove the parentheses from around the macro invocation.

Comment: do you want `#define ITERATE_ALL10(IDX) IDX = 0; IDX < 10; IDX++` ?

Comment: you should do `#define DO_ALL(IDX) IDX = 0; IDX <= MAX_IDX; ++IDX`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two errors in your code.

First, you use the token pasting operator `##` incorrectly. This operator is used to paste two tokens to make a new token, e.g. `foo ## bar` yields `foobar`. You don't need it in your code, just drop it.

After fixing this issue, your macro looks like this:

```
#define ITERATE_ALL10(IDX) (IDX = 0; IDX < 10; IDX++)
```

This is how the expansion looks:

```
for ((i = 0; i < 10; i++)) {
```

Notice that there is a redundant pair of parentheses, which is what throws off the compiler. Either remove the parentheses from the macro definition:

```
#define ITERATE_ALL10(IDX) IDX = 0; IDX < 10; IDX++
```

or remove the parentheses from the macro invocation:

```
for ITERATE_ALL10(i)
```

I prefer the former.

Comment: I prefer `for (i=0; i<10; i++) { ... }`. Can't see the point of  this macro definition at all.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage This comment should go on the "question" and not an "answer".

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I think he has a lot of those functions and tries to somehow make things easier, but fails at it.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the parentheses from the macro definition or remove the parentheses from around the macro invocation.  You also need to remove the token pasting operator `##` because you don't have two tokens to paste.

Either:

```
#define ITERATE_ALL10(IDX) IDX = 0; IDX < 10; IDX++

for (ITERATE_ALL10(i)) {
```

Or:

```
#define ITERATE_ALL10(IDX) (IDX = 0; IDX < 10; IDX++)

for ITERATE_ALL10(i) {
```

I don't particularly recommend either solution, but they should work.  Your code (amended to fix the problem with `##`) generates:

```
for ((i = 0; i < 10; i++)) {
```

and the double parentheses wreck the syntax.